# Scrape scrape scrape above 40mph. Goes away when I turn right or hit the brakes

Tags: noise

A guy rear ended me the other day. Of course, he didn't have insurance. Anyhow, so my car starts making this scrape scrape scrape sound above 40mph but it goes away when you press on the brakes.

At first I thought it might be the rear brake because I've heard that scrape sound before with drum brakes and I thought the jolt might have knocked the shoe out of place. Then I noticed it also goes away when I turn to the right so I figured it must be coming from one of the front tires instead of the rear tires.

I take the front tires off and the calipers and brake pads look fine. Then I notice the tie rod end on the passenger side is loose. I can wiggle the tie rod end where it connects to the control arm. Maybe I was hearing a thump thump thump not a scrape scrape scrape. You think the problem could be the loose tie rod end?

Comment: It could be something rubbing against a tire which moves away from the tire when braking.

Answer (score 1):

Take it to a garage and get it checked. Just because the other driver doesn't have insurance, doesn't mean he's not liable; hopefully he was cited, and you can get all his details.

Even if you can't get money out of him, get it checked. If it's serious, you may be able to claim on your own insurance (and they will go after the deadbeat)

Comment: In addition, just because the other driver is a deadbeat doesn't mean you're not at risk because of damage to your car. Get it checked.

Comment: btw it was the wheel bearing. Dang thing was looser than a BLM rioter in Portland. I had replaced the bearing a few months back (I drive the car a lot though) so maybe I messed something up. But I had a shop press the bearing. Anyways, $50 for a junkyard stearing knuckle with the bearing and three hours of work and I was back on the road.